# Marten JasperFx - How to ignore property of class when document is generated

Tags: postgresql, marten, nosql

Its possible ignore class property when [Marten](http://jasperfx.github.io/marten/) store document on database?

Eg.:

```
    public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Ignore this when create a document on DB]
        public Date DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLVED**

```
public class Test
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [IgnoreDataMember]
   public Date DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL:DR

Marten just uses Newtonsoft.Json under the hood, so to ignore property, use Newtonsoft [JsonIgnoreAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm):

```cs
public class Account
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
}
```

## Explanation

This seems to be question visible on top of google search so I'd like to add my 50 cents.

Since MartenDB use internally Newtonsoft.Json then all attributes from this lib should work fine. I don't know about Igor [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45333275/4672934), couldn't confirm this anywhere in library so it seems to be outdated at the moment.

### From [docs](https://martendb.io/documentation/documents/json/):

> An absolutely essential ingredient in Marten's persistence strategy is JSON serialization of the document objects. Marten aims to make the JSON serialization extensible and configurable through the native mechanisms in each JSON serialization library. For the purposes of having a smooth "getting started" story, Marten comes out of the box with support for a very basic usage of Newtonsoft.Json as the main JSON serializer.

## About Newtonsoft.json in MartenDB

MartenDB isn't tied to Newtonsoft.json, you could always write own adapter for other library.

All you have to do is implement `ISerializer` interface:

```cs
public interface ISerializer
{
    void ToJson(object document, TextWriter writer);

    string ToJson(object document);

    T FromJson<T>(TextReader reader);

    object FromJson(Type type, TextReader reader);

    string ToCleanJson(object document);

    EnumStorage EnumStorage { get; }

    Casing Casing { get; }

    CollectionStorage CollectionStorage { get; }

    NonPublicMembersStorage NonPublicMembersStorage { get; }
}
```

More detailed example: [docs](https://martendb.io/documentation/documents/json/jil/)

Comment: Hi @Rafał Kopczyński! Consider put more information in your "answer", like: How to ignore property?

Comment: @Igor you are right, I updated my answer.